# Why n-dimensional vector group doesn't have multiplication and divsion?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Yesterday, I started learning group theory.

Then I found a sample group theory definition like following (translated from japanese by me):

> For example, consider the set V of all n-dimensional vectors. Addition
> and subtraction are defined in V. However, multiplication and division
> are not defined. Therefore, if we build a general theory about "sets
> in which addition and subtraction are defined", we can apply it to all
> things with similar properties. This is a "group".

But I think it's weird. Because if we have two sample vectors like V1 and V2, it can be multiplied at least.

```
// 2-dimentional vector
>>> V1 = torch.randn(2,2)

// 3-dimentional vector
>>> V2 = torch.randn(2,2,2)
>>> V1*V2
tensor([[[-0.4868,  0.6598],
         [-0.2150, -0.4340]],

        [[-0.2066,  0.2782],
         [-0.0213, -1.5037]]])
```

I can't determine whether,
we define the "group" which have addition and subtraction not multiplication in this context
**OR**
originally set V of all n-dimensional vectors has addition and subtraction not multiplication.

Any suggestion ?

**EDIT**

Thank you all.
I misunderstood vector and matrix, and I didn't know multiplication on various situation

Comment: The set of all $n$-vectors has a binary operation called addition under which it forms a group. You can go ahead and define a multiplication on this set however you like, but you'll find that the interesting definitions don't give the set a group structure, and the operations that give it a group structure aren't interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplication you used is not one of the usual products used for, say, matrices.

It's referred to as "pointwise multiplication". Also, since the dimensions of the tensors do not match up, there will be "broadcasting" as well.

In mathematics, the matrix product is defined very differently.

On another note, the first tensor you created is not a 2-dimensional vector, but a $2 \times 2$-dimensional matrix; the second one is a $2 \times 2 \times 2$-dimensional tensor.

When talking about linear algebra in the most abstract sense, a vector space consists of two sets, a set of vectors and a set of scalars. There are also a few binary operators on these sets, such as "vector addition" and such. I recommend you look for a formal definition of a vector space. It is a much broader concept than just $n$-dimensional vectors over $\mathbb{R}$. For example, the set of all differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}^3$ is a vector space.

We can multiply vectors by scalars, but not necessarily by other vectors. There are some vector spaces where we have an "inner product", where multiplying two vectors results in a scalar. In $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{C}^3$ there is another product, the "cross-product", which *does* return a vector when we multiply two vectors, but that's a very specific case.

The pointwise vector product does not appear very often in mathematics. It is common in computer science, which is why many libraries for various programming languages implement it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the multiplication of two vectors in a way that someone who doesn't know torch can understand. In two dimensions there is no multiplication of two vectors that gives a vector and satisfies the field axioms.  You can certainly define a multiplication of two vectors, but you can't have it be commutative, associative, and distribute over addition properly.  In three dimensions you have the cross product, but it is not commutative or associative.  If multiplication does not relate to addition, you really have two separate structures on a set that do not relate to each other.  They could both be groups, for example, but there is no advantage in having both because they don't talk to each other.  Everything you do, you have to choose which one you will use and the other doesn't matter.